# Is this sequence monotone?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm to determine whether a series converges or not and for that i need to know whether this 
$$\{a_n\}=\dfrac{1+nx}{\sqrt{n^2+n^6x^2}}$$
is an non-increasing sequence. I already tried to put $a_n>a_{n+1}$ and see where that leads to but i got lost in huge polynoms. Any hint to solve it smarter?

Comment: Dividing through by $n$ yields $$\frac {\frac 1n+x}{\sqrt{1+n^4x^2}}$$...  Then note that for all $n\gt 0$, $\frac 1{n+1}+x\le \frac 1n+x$ and $\sqrt{1+(n+1)^4x^2}\ge \sqrt{1+n^4x^2}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applying division by $n$, we have

$$\{a_n\}=\frac {1+nx}{\sqrt{n^2+n^6x^2}}=\frac{\frac 1n+x}{\sqrt{1+n^4x^2}}$$

For all $n\gt 0$, we have $\frac 1{n+1}\le \frac 1n$ which means that $\frac 1{n+1}+x\le\frac 1n+x$, and we further have $0\le 1+n^4x^2\le 1+(n+1)^4x^2$, and also that $\sqrt y$ is an increasing function for $y\in[0,\infty)$.

The only limitation is if $x\lt 0$, in which case there exists an $N$ such that $\forall n\gt N,0\ge a_{n+1}\ge a_n$.  Taking the domain of $x$ as $x\in[0,\infty)$, we then have

$$0\le\frac {\frac 1{n+1}+x}{\sqrt{1+(n+1)^4x^2}}\le\frac{\frac 1n+x}{\sqrt{1+(n+1)^4x^2}}\le\frac{\frac 1n+x}{\sqrt{1+n^4x^2}}$$

which means that $a_{n+1}\le a_n$.

Comment: what makes the $x<0$ option be the other way around?

Comment: If $x\lt 0$, we still have $x^2\gt 0$.  But there exists an $N$ such that for all $n\gt N, \frac 1n\lt |x|$ which means that $x+\frac 1n\lt 0$ when $x\lt 0$.  The sequence still goes to $0$ eventually, but since there exists a finite $N$ for which it goes negative, it must then approach $0$ from the negative side, which means that it is increasing.

Comment: But $\frac1{n+1}+x$ is still smaller than $\frac1{n}+x$ or not?

Comment: $\frac 1{n+1}\le \frac 1n$ regardless of the positive value $n$ takes on, but from the negative side, the $\frac 1{\sqrt{1+n^4x^2}}$ portion still dominates and takes the sequence in the positive direction towards $0$.

Comment: Ah so the $\frac{\frac1{n}+x}{\sqrt{1+n^4x^2}}\ge\frac{\frac1{n}+x}{\sqrt{1+(n+1)^4x^2}}$ isn't true. - And I can use the opposite to prove that it increases.

Comment: For negative $x$, that is correct.  That is why I qualified the domain of $x$ prior to writing that inequality.  For positive $x$, the inequality holds.  Basically, you do not have a monotone sequence if $x\lt 0$, while you do have a monotone sequence if $x\ge 0$.